# Sort objects in List by String (dd/mm/yyyy)?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, list, sorting

Can someone help me with this? I can't find any example..

I've created a Java Class called Subtaks with multiple fields. And i'm trying to sort a list of Subtasks. Firt I'm sorting the list alphabetically with one field called status; but if this field is the same i'm trying to sort it by another String field that containt a date with this format:

```
String resolutionDate = "18/09/2014"
```

I've implemented this method to sort it:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Subtask o) {
    if (this.status.equals(o.status))
        return o.resolutiondate.compareTo(this.resolutiondate);
    else
        return this.status.compareTo(o.status);
}
```

Comment: What's the behavior that you're getting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: First and foremost don't use string type for date sort. Please convert that to Date. You can find my complete answer posted below.

Comment: You might want to learn about [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to sort by date so you'd either have to manually extract year, day and month and compare them or parse the date and compare the parsed dates.

For the first approach, you could use something like this:

```
String  resolutionDateReordered = resolutionDate.replaceAll("(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)","$3$2$1");
```

And then compare `resolutionDateReordered`. This assumes that the parts of the date have equal length, i.e. 2-digit day and month and 4 digit year and would reorder the string "18/09/2014" to "20140918", which then would be sortable by date.

This could be optimized by creating the pattern once and reusing it, e.g.

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})" ); //pattern slightly changed to expect 2-digit day and month and 4-digit year.

and in your compare() method:

String resolutionDateReordered = p.matcher( resolutionDate ).replaceAll(  "$3$2$1" );

As for the second approach you do something like this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date resolutionDateParsed = df.parse( resolutionDate );
```

And then compare `resolutionDateParsed` using Date's `compareTo()` method.

Depending on the size of the list, the first or second approach might be faster, but YMMV. For example, on my machine sorting a list of date strings having your format using the optimized version of the string reordering is approx. twice as fast as parsing first and comapring the dates, with 3.5 seconds vs. 7.4 seconds for 100k entries.

Comment: If you do want to sort by date, then it's possible that String isn't the best datatype. Java provides Calendar to deal with date (It's possible that that's not the up to date version, I forget)

Comment: @Yann4 that depends, using Date is definitely the more intuitive approach but if you can't change the input, i.e. you have a date as a string it might yield better performance to just reorder the string and compare strings but ymmv.

Answer (score 1):

First you convert your `String` value of date("dd/mm/yyyy") to type of `Date(java.util)`

```
public class YourClassName implements Comparable<YourClassName> {

    ....

    //return -1 for less than, 0 for equals, and 1 for more than
    public compareTo(Subtask subTask) {
        int result = 0;
        result = getResolutionDate().compareTo(subTask.getResolutionDate());
        if (result != 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        result = getStatus().compareTo(subTask.getStatus());
        if (result != 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Would that sort correctly or would "19/01/2013" be greater than "18/09/2014"? ...

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the SubTask class:**

```
package com.test.main;

import java.util.Date;

public class Subtask implements Comparable<Subtask> {

    private String status;
    private Date resolutionDate;

    public Subtask(String status, Date resolutionDate) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.resolutionDate = resolutionDate;
    }


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }


    public Date getResolutionDate() {
        return resolutionDate;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Subtask o) {
        int compareToIgnoreCase = status.compareToIgnoreCase(o.getStatus());
        return compareToIgnoreCase==0?resolutionDate.compareTo(o.getResolutionDate()):compareToIgnoreCase;
    }

}
```

**Main method:**

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Subtask> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.setTime(new Date());
        arrayList.add(new Subtask("test1", instance.getTime()));
        instance.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        arrayList.add(new Subtask("test1", instance.getTime()));
        instance.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
        arrayList.add(new Subtask("test1", instance.getTime()));
        Collections.sort(arrayList);

        for (Subtask subtask : arrayList) {
            System.out.println(subtask.getResolutionDate());
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.